# Retrieve data every 2 minutes from SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, vb.net-2010

I am doing a chart about water sensor measurement. 3 measurements are made and stored in table "Sensor" every minute.

For my purposes, I need data at 2 minutes intervals. That is, I will get 5  readings (15 rows in total) for 10 minutes worth of data recorded.

Here is the example:

```
RecordDate                 Depth
-----------------------------------
2016-01-01  07:01:00        112
2016-01-01  07:01:00        116
2016-01-01  07:01:00        108
2016-01-01  07:00:00        106
2016-01-01  07:00:00        102
2016-01-01  07:00:00        103
2016-01-01  06:59:00        111
2016-01-01  06:59:00        110
2016-01-01  06:59:00        109
2016-01-01  06:58:00        108
2016-01-01  06:58:00        107
2016-01-01  06:58:00        106
2016-01-01  06:57:00        109
2016-01-01  06:57:00        104
2016-01-01  06:57:00        105
2016-01-01  06:56:00        112
2016-01-01  06:56:00        114
2016-01-01  06:56:00        115
2016-01-01  06:55:00        102
2016-01-01  06:55:00        104
2016-01-01  06:55:00        105
2016-01-01  06:54:00        108
2016-01-01  06:54:00        109
2016-01-01  06:54:00        112
2016-01-01  06:53:00        113
2016-01-01  06:53:00        115
2016-01-01  06:53:00        117
2016-01-01  06:52:00        105
2016-01-01  06:52:00        109
2016-01-01  06:52:00        112
```

Expected records result:

```
2016-01-01  07:01:00        112
2016-01-01  07:01:00        116
2016-01-01  07:01:00        108
2016-01-01  06:59:00        111
2016-01-01  06:59:00        110
2016-01-01  06:59:00        109
2016-01-01  06:57:00        109
2016-01-01  06:57:00        104
2016-01-01  06:57:00        105
2016-01-01  06:55:00        102
2016-01-01  06:55:00        104
2016-01-01  06:55:00        105
2016-01-01  06:53:00        113
2016-01-01  06:53:00        115
2016-01-01  06:53:00        117
```

My SQL query to get 10 minutes records:

```
Declare @LastTime datetime

select top 1 @LastTime = RecordDate  
from Sensor 
order by RecordDate desc

select * 
from Sensor 
where datediff(n, RecordDate, @LastTime) > 10
```

So how can I get data every 2 minutes based using SQL?

Or if it's not easy, is it ok to filter Dataset in VB.net.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Are you expecting SQL or .NET to push the data to some client every X minutes?

Comment: It would be great to do in SQL store_proc. But if it's hard to do this way, I can return dataset and filter condition in .net code. Thanks.

Comment: That doesn't actually answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

if you want data in .net application every x amount of time, then you should make use of [`Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) which can help you to get data at x amount of time , for example , code from MSDN

```
    private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

   public static void Main()
   {
      SetTimer();

      Console.WriteLine("\nPress the Enter key to exit the application...\n");
      Console.WriteLine("The application started at {0:HH:mm:ss.fff}", DateTime.Now);
      Console.ReadLine();
      aTimer.Stop();
      aTimer.Dispose();

      Console.WriteLine("Terminating the application...");
   }

   private static void SetTimer()
   {
        // Create a timer with a two second interval.
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
        aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        aTimer.AutoReset = true;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0:HH:mm:ss.fff}",
                          e.SignalTime);
    }
```

Code is in C# but you can convert to Vb.net,